# Elementary proof that $\mathbb{E}[1/X] \geq 1/\mathbb{E}[X]$ for finitely supported positive random variables.

Tags: probability, jensen-inequality

Let $X$ be a random variable with finite support contained in $(0,\infty)$. By Jensen's inequality we have $\mathbb{E}[1/X] \geq 1/\mathbb{E}[X]$. I am curious if there exists an elementary proof of this fact which avoids the use of Jensen's inequality.

To rephrase the setup in an elementary way:

Let $S$ be a finite set of positive real numbers, and let $f : S \to [0,1]$ be a function such that $\sum_{s \in S} f(s) = 1$. Then we want to show that

$$\sum_{s \in S} f(s)/s \geq \left(\sum_{s \in S} f(s) s \right)^{-1}.$$

Equivalently, we want to show that

$$\sum_{s, s' \in S} f(s)f(s') \frac{s}{s'} \geq 1.$$

**What is the most elementary proof of this fact? In particular, is there a nice proof which avoids arguing by induction?** I would like to present a proof of this to students who are good at algebraic manipulation but who haven't learned Jensen's inequality and are not so comfortable with writing proofs by induction.

---

Here's something that might be useful:

$$\operatorname{Cov}(X,1/X) = \mathbb{E}[X(1/X)] - \mathbb{E}[X]\mathbb{E}[1/X] = 1-\mathbb{E}[X]\mathbb{E}[1/X],$$

We should expect that $X$ and $1/X$ are nonpositively correlated, because when $X$ is relatively large $1/X$ is relatively small, and visa-versa. *If we can prove this*, then we have $1 - \mathbb{E}[X]\mathbb{E}[1/X] \leq 0$, and we are done.

Comment: It looks to me like you're asking for an elementary proof that $f(x)=1/x$ is convex on $(0,\infty)$. Is that right?

Comment: Not exactly -- as specified in the question, I am seeking a proof which specifically avoids using Jensen's inequality. It is easy to provide an elementary proof that $x \mapsto 1/x$ is convex on $(0,\infty)$, but getting from there to the desired result is not as straightforward.

Comment: Another way to rephrase my question is that I am looking for a proof of this special case of Jensen's inequality which does not go by induction.

Comment: Thanks; I do understand that. Also please note that I did specifically include this desideratum in the question. I will edit the question and put it in bold :)

Comment: Yes. My mistake. Apologies.

Comment: This proof hardly seems all that "elementary" to me!

Comment: Well the problem is precisely that I don't have an elementary proof :) it doesn't seem impossible, however, that there does exist an elementary proof for this specific inequality, just because $x \mapsto 1/x$ is such a particular function.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It can be proved by exploiting the monotonicity of the function $x \mapsto 1/x$ on $(0, \infty)$. Let $X_1, X_2 \text{ i.i.d. } \sim X$. It is easy to verify by monotonicity that
\begin{align*}
(X_1 - X_2)\left(\frac{1}{X_1} - \frac{1}{X_2}\right) \leq 0.
\end{align*}
Taking expectations on both sides and using the i.i.d. of $X_1, X_2$ then yields
\begin{align}
1 - E[X_1]E\left[\frac{1}{X_2}\right] - E[X_2]E\left[\frac{1}{X_1}\right] + 1
= 2 - 2E[X]E\left[\frac{1}{X}\right]\leq 0, 
\end{align}
which is the desired inequality.

Comment: Beautiful, thank you!

Comment: (+1) I really like this proof, not because it's elementary but because it's deceptive in its complexity.  Specifically, the statement "Let $X_1, X_2 \text{ i.i.d. } \sim X$" sneaks in a theoretical framework that is, in my opinion, significantly less elementary than Jensen's inequality.  Even so, it's a good example of why working in the correct framework can yield nice proofs.

Comment: @BrianMoehring Totally agree.  It is like using a multivariate calculus tool to prove a univariate calculus problem :).

Comment: To disclose the "deceptive complexity" and justify (usually take for granted) the correctness of the statement "Let $X_1, X_2 \text{ i.i.d. } \sim X$", please refer to Theorem 20.4 in *Probability and Measure* by Patrick Billingsley, which is indeed quite technical and profound.